# Repeated tasks - spawn new processes or run continuously?

Tags: methods, process, long-integer

We have about 10 different Python scripts that download data from the web, read data from a database and write data back to that database. They do so repeatedly every 10 seconds (or 10 seconds after the last task has completed).

The question is, what is the best approach at running these tasks? I can think of a few ways:

1. a while True that runs the task then sleeps for the interval. It could be guarded by a watchdog like supervisord, making sure it is always up.
2. having the script execute the task just once, and invoking the script externally once every 10 seconds by another process.
3. having the script execute the task lets say for 1 hour (every 10 seconds for an hour), and having a watchdog make sure that task runs again once the hour is over.

I would like to avoid long running processes that actually do something because I don't want to deal with memory problems etc over long periods of time.

**Additional Information**

1. The scripts are different because they each retrieve data from a different source, and query, calculate and insert different data into the database.
2. The tasks are performed every 10 seconds since the data being retrieve is in real-time, and we need to not only keep updating it very frequently, but also keep all the historical data in the database.
3. There are a lot of resources being used by the scripts - MySQL connections, HTTP connections, Redis connections, etc. We have encountered issues with using the long-running approach before, specifically with MySQL connections (things like MySQL server has gone away, even though all connections had been closed). Hence the inclination toward having the scripts run in shorter periods of time.

What are some common approaches at this?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your scripts somehow leak memory (quite unlikely), they should all be the same. So, for sheer simplicity (*your* time programming/debugging is much more expensive than a few miliseconds of the machine's time, even each 10 seconds!) I'd go for the single script that checks each 10 seconds.

OTOH, checking each 10 seconds sounds like busywork. Can't you set up so that whatever you are monitoring tells you when there are changes? Or batch the records up so you can retrieve, say, a day's worth at at time?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on linux, cron has granularity of a minute. We have processes we run constantly. Rather than watch them, the script will open a semaphore that gets released when the program finishes normally or not. This way if it runs long and it gets called again by cron, the copy will exit when it can't get the lock. This way you can call it a often as you need to without it stepping on a possibly still running copy.